# Setting contextType for UITextField is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

No idea why but my `textField` is not responding to setting the `contextType`...

This is how how I create the `textField`:

```
let emailTextField: UITextField = {
    let v = UITextField()
    v.textColor = .white
    v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 17)
    v.placeholder = "Email-Adresse"
    v.textContentType = .emailAddress
    v.minimumFontSize = 13
    v.borderStyle = .line
    v.autocapitalizationType = .none
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
```

It's being displayed just fine and everything works but the `contextType`... It is just showing the standard keyboard. Am I doing anything wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keyboardType to set keyboard like below:

```
v.keyboardType = .emailAddress
```

Comment: oh. What is contentType doing then?

Comment: I hope keyboardType helped you in what you were looking for. By setting context type field expect an email or whatever type you chooses.

Comment: @Chris I mostly prefer using keyboardType with contextType.

Comment: By just setting context type, it expects type and in some cases it may choose keyboard on its own whatever it thinks is best. So use keyboardType as well as contextType.